# Jquery-File-Upload adding form data

Tags: jquery-file-upload

I am trying to follow the documentation to add form data to JQuery-File-Upload and then process it on my server side php upload handler.

I have added the following to my webpage:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="/server/php/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="row">
<label>Example: <input type="text" name="example1"></label>
</div>
```

and then I am trying to use this in my UploadHandler.php file as such:

```
protected function get_user_path() {
    if ($this->options['user_dirs']) {
        return $this->$POST['example1'].'/';
    }
    return '';
}
```

With the hope that it will make the upload folder whatever the text written into example1 is. I thought this would work because it states this in the wiki:

> e.g. an additional input field with the name attribute example1 will
>   arrive on server-side as POST parameter example1.

and if I replace `$POST['example1']` with just `'test'` then it does place it in a folder called test.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have `$POST`, it should be `$_POST['example1']`

Comment: for some reason, it wasn't working when written as `$_POST['example1']`, but then while fiddling around with it, all I did was change the name to `$_POST['name']` which is what I wanted to call the field, and it worked. So yay, your answer was correct!